# You have two days for this project

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, informal-language

if employer or teacher or anyone tells me during anytime on Monday that I have 2 days to give him the files or to finish the project.

I ask: How much time do I get/have?
The employer, teacher says:  You have two days!

Should I always count it as extra two days meaning that if today is Monday it HAS to be delivered/finished at latest on Wednesday 23:59?

It NEVER ever means that I have only some time left from today + tomorrow and that it has to be delivered on Tuesday by 23:59 right?

Please, explain thank you very much!

Comment: I think you need to ask instead "when is the deadline?"  "Two days" is not meaningful on its own.

Comment: Native English speakers would know to ask. If today is Monday at 9:am, I'd ask, "Do you want it Wednesday or Thursday?

Comment: @WillowRex I think you mean "Do you want it Tuesday or Wednesday"... but, if it were Monday at 9 am, and someone told me that I had two days, that would mean it was due Tuesday end of business... that means you get all day Monday and all day Tuesday.

Comment: @Catija  This precisely why you ask, there IS a possibility that they want it Tuesday by the end of the day, but that needs clarifying. That would not be the way I would word it, if I were boss. I'd say, "I need it tomorrow (Tuesday) at 4:pm."

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unlikely that your boss or teacher will tell you something generic like "you have two days" without also telling you the day of the week or date it's due.

But, if that were the case, you should ask for more specific information because there's no one correct answer.

Let's start with a couple of work examples.

1. It's 9 am Monday. You're given a project and told "you have two days to complete this project".

This *generally* means you have two *work days*... so that means you have all day Monday and all day Tuesday. The project is due end of day Tuesday... usually meaning whenever you go home for the day (5 pm). You might be able to say it's due first thing Wednesday morning as that's effectively the same thing.

2. It's 5 pm Monday and your boss gives you a project and tells you "you have two days to complete this project".

In this case, you're about to go home for the day, so this is your assignment for the next two days... Tuesday and Wednesday. The project is due end of business on Wednesday (or first thing Thursday morning).

In either example, the result is the same... two full work days to do the task.

Similarly, in a school situation, if the teacher gives you two days, that usually means you have two days from today... so if it's Monday, you have until your class period on Wednesday, although some teachers who allow digital submissions of work will give until midnight - this should be spelled out specifically by your teacher, though; don't expect it to be standard.

So, the "safe" bet is to take today's time and add 48 hours to it and assume that's when it's due.